# Class Inflector not found after installing uploader 4.* plugin to cakephp using composer

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, uploader

After i installed uploader plugin in cakephp i received the following error
NB: I used composer to install uploader dependency.

Fatal error: Class 'Inflector' not found in /home/*****/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 748

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a missing `App::uses('Inflector', 'Utility')` in the App.php file
See https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/1201

Comment: Note: This is fixed in the current master branch now.